# Using "db2 text search" on db2 on cloud (formerly dashdb)

Tags: fuzzy-search, dashdb

I need to perform a fuzzy search using db2 on cloud (formerly dashdb).

The name of the product I need to use is "Db2 Text Search". Here are the details on the announcement: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.ts.doc/doc/c0051296.html

Does anyone know if this is possible for db2 on cloud?

If not, can you please share with me how you would solve the problem of having a fuzzy search? 
Thanks

Comment: AFAIU Db2 Text Search is not supported on Db2 on Cloud nor Db2 Warehouse on Cloud at this time.

Comment: thanks Paul, I have also received this answer from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

What *exactly* do you mean by "fuzzy"?  Maybe update your question with an example

You might be best using regular expressions with e.g. `REGEXP_LIKE()`

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0061494.html